# strange behaviour of getElementById() and .split() method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";

};


function executeFunc()  {

    var cookieData=document.cookie.split(';');
    for(entry in cookieData)
    {
        createCookie(cookieData[entry],"",-1); //clear the cookie first
    }
    createCookie("node-1","1",365);
    createCookie("node-2","1",365);
    createCookie("node-3","1",365);

    alert("the cookie contains : " + document.cookie);

    var cookie=document.cookie.split(';');

        for(ele in cookie)
        {
            var node=cookie[ele].split('=');


            alert(node[0]);  //this prints the next node correctly
            var nodeId=document.getElementById(node[0]); //for the first 
                     //iteration i get the row in 
                     //nodeId correctly but for the next iterations, i get null, 
                     //althought the row exists. if i type in the row Id manually 
                     //it works, but if i use node[0] then it returns null !! :S
            alert("the node is : " + nodeId);

            alert(document.cookie);



        }


}


</script>
<body onLoad="executeFunc()">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="node-1">
    <td>im node 1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="node-2">
    <td>im node 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="node-3">
    <td>im node 3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

first of all i dint know how to run the above code on Jsfiddle and then link it to my question. sorry for that!!

In executeFunc() in javascript, i am spliting the cookie entries and extracting the names in "node" variable. then using this name, i get the row object and print it. when it loops for the first time, everything goes as planned but for the next iterations, `alert(node[0])` prints the next entry in the cookie(i.e node-2) but `nodeId=document.getElementById(node[0])` returns null. if i change it to `nodeId=document.getElementById("node-2")` it works fine. i dont knw wat the prblm is..you can test it by just copy pasting it...its the complete code!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cookie has a space in front of each identifier.  Thus, it tries to look up `" node-1"` and doesn't find it.  You can see the spaces in this version of your code with quote marks around the alert text: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZS3HB/.

I'd suggest either revising the split to `split('; ')` or trim leading/trailing spaces off the identifiers before using them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are splitting on `';'`, but there is a space after each semicolon, so the second node name ends up as `" node-2"` instead of `"node-2"`.

If you split on `'; '` instead, it will work.

Alternatively, you can remove the space from the name:

```
if (node[0].charAt(0) == ' ') {
  node[0] = node[0].substr(1);
}
```